# Stormpath Rest api PHP

Tags: php, rest, stormpath

can someone help me write this in the form of an httpRequest in php. I´ve tried many times and failed. I don´t know why but I simply can´t get it right.

curl -i --user $YOUR_API_KEY_ID:$YOUR_API_KEY_SECRET \
  'https://api.stormpath.com/v1/tenants/current'

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the PHP you've tried.

Comment: @Jon Stirling, I tried using terminal in ubuntu but error occured, curl: (1) Protocol " https" not supported or disabled in libcurl.

Comment: In your cURL command? What OS?

Comment: There is an extra space before ‘https’.

Comment: @JonStirling, Iam using Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

Comment: @Petr Duchek, I didn't find any extra space before 'https', can you please little explore, where you are directing.

Comment: The backslash tells the shell to "ignore the next character." Remove backslash from your *one line command* or add new line after backslash.

Answer (score 0):

So for you to get the current tenant within PHP, you will need to let curl follow redirects as `/tenant/current` is a 302 redirect to the tenant for your API key

```
<?php


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.stormpath.com/v1/tenants/current");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($YOUR_API_KEY_ID:$YOUR_API_KEY_SECRET);
$headers[] = "Accept: application/json";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
var_dump($server_output);
```

With this, it will return your current tenant resource.

For reference, Stormpath does have an open PHP SDK that you can use instead so you dont have to mess with cURL at all.

[Stormpath PHP SDK](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-php)

The SDK is installable via `Composer` and is in a stable release state as of 1.12.0